# How to compress an HDR video

Tags: avfoundation, hdr, video-toolbox

I have been trying to use VTCompressionSession to compress an HDR video recorded on iPhone - but it comes out as very "washed out". I tried using HEVC codec as well, but that still gives me the same result.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Tag it as HLG...

Comment: Which one is that in this list: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremedia/cmformatdescription/1564239-video_codec_constants

Comment: Neither. This one: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcolorspace/3571187-itur_2100_hlg/

Comment: Use this as the codec  in VTCompressionSessionCreate?